# Yammer login to web app not working on Iphone

Tags: iphone, mobile, authentication, redirect, yammer

Recently i registered app on yammer to use yammer for login to my web app. There is a problem on iOS with this flow, because when i try to login I get mobile yammer app login pop up & after that it only opens yammer app, and no redirection to my web app actually happens.

This only happens on iphone, on all other devices it works, on android also works with yammer app installed. Somebody familiar with this ?

Comment: Which OAuth flow from https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2 are you using? Does it work when the app is not installed?

Comment: hey Brian, tnx for comment, it is working when app is not installed, also starts working after reinstalling the app (but this is kinda cumbersome workaround imo)...
it is server side flow